# Marking "Ambidextrous" in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

*This is an example that illustrates my problem*

So I have a table of participants, each with their own unique ID number. They all do a writing test and their time, in minutes, is recorded in the fourth column as an integer. Some patients have repeated the test, there is no maximum number of repeats.

```
+============+===========+===============+======+
| Patient ID | Hand Used | Ambidextrous? | Time |
+============+===========+===============+======+
|         01 | Right     | Yes           |   12 |
+------------+-----------+---------------+------+
|         01 | Right     | Yes           |   10 |
+------------+-----------+---------------+------+
|         01 | Right     | Yes           |   11 |
+------------+-----------+---------------+------+
|         01 | Left      | Yes           |   13 |
+------------+-----------+---------------+------+
|         01 | Right     | Yes           |   12 |
+------------+-----------+---------------+------+
|         02 | Right     | No            |    9 |
+------------+-----------+---------------+------+
|         02 | Right     | No            |    7 |
+------------+-----------+---------------+------+
|         02 | Right     | No            |    8 |
+------------+-----------+---------------+------+
|         03 | Left      | Yes           |    8 |
+------------+-----------+---------------+------+
|         03 | Right     | Yes           |    8 |
+------------+-----------+---------------+------+
```

I want the "Ambidextrous?" column to be a formula. I've been trying to accomplish this with INDEX() and MATCH(), to no avail. It needs to check the "Hand Used" column, if there is both a Right handed and Left handed test for a particular Patient ID, we say "Yes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,IF(B2="Right","Left","Right")),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: You just missed one `"` after the `Yes`, but this is absolutely genius